# Availability Report Error

Tags: report

Hye, I have a problem with Orion NMS. Whenever I try to created availability report for next month there is an error came out from my browser. Kindly refer below.

Orion Website Error
An error has occurred with the Orion website.

Additional Information

System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

I try to add increase timeout at "Report Cache Timeout" from Orion Website setting. But whenever I click submit the valued not change, value remain same.

Appreciate if someone have any idea or solution for this kind of problem.